# c# print directly to Brother label printer using custom page length without bPac

Tags: c#, printing, brother-bpac

I am successfully printing labels directly to a Brother QL label printer using the code below.  The problem is that the printer seems to be ignoring the custom length I am trying to set at run time via c# to result in a longer or shorter label.  I can change the page length in Windows Printer Settings but I am unable to set a custom label length at run time which would be dependent on the amount of information I'm rendering on a particular label.  Note that I know I can use bPac to print a variable length label but I would really like to get away from using their templates.  I've found them to be unnecessarily cumbersome.  Well, unnecessary unless I'm unable to set a custom length otherwise.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void SingleLabel()
{
    label = new PrintDocument();

    PaperSize pS = new PaperSize("Custom Size", 242, 55);
    label.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pS;
    label.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Label_1";
    label.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pS;
    label.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(label_PrintPage);
    label.Print();
}

private void label_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Font header = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold);

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", header, brush, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it in such way

```
   public void OnPagePrint(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
        var availableWidth = 220;
        var printAreaSize = DrawReceipt(availableWidth, e.Graphics, GetReceiptContent());
        e.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("CustomPaperSize", (int)printAreaSize.Width + 10, (int)printAreaSize.Height);
    }

    public SizeF DrawReceipt(float availableWidth, Graphics graphics, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        var printText = new PrintText(sb.ToString(), new Font("Consolas", 8));
        var layoutArea = new SizeF(availableWidth, 0);
        SizeF stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(printText.Text, printText.Font, layoutArea, printText.StringFormat);
        RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(new PointF(), new SizeF(availableWidth, stringSize.Height));
        graphics.DrawString(printText.Text, printText.Font, Brushes.Black, rectf, printText.StringFormat);

        foreach (var img in images)
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(img.Image, img.Location);
        }

        return stringSize;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but when I compile and execute your code above the label printer still spits out the exact same length label each time.  I try to print several lines on the label via your code and the extra lines just get cut off.

Comment: are you adding lines by StringBuilder AppendLine? it adds line terminator to the string and MeasureString should get correct stringSize.Height

Comment: Yes, to test, I edited your code in the below way.   The label prints out the same length each time and cuts off lines 8 through 10.                                                                                                       public StringBuilder GetReceiptContent()
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("StringBuilder string");
            s.AppendLine("Line2");
//               ...
            s.AppendLine("Line7");
            s.AppendLine("Line8");
            s.AppendLine("Line9");
            s.AppendLine("Line10");

            return s;
        }

Comment: did you remove PaperSize setup from the SingleLabel()?

Comment: Yes, I used your code above exactly and the label length does not change.  I think there is something about this particular model label printer which ignores a custom label length.